# How to keep column referencing constant with column names in Excel when dragging to other columns

Tags: excel-formula

Ok so I am trying to do something like... this we have three columns with data say column A is called Multiplier, Column B is called Value 1 and Column C is called Value 2. I want to have Column D be Multiplier by Value 1 and then drag it to column E to do Multiplier by Value 2. For example if I do  [@[Multiplier]]*[@[Value 1]] in Cell D2 then drag to E2 it changes to [@[Value 1]]*[@[Value 2]] when I want it to be [@[Multiplier]]*[@[Value 2]].

I know if I was doing this with absolute referencing I would do something like =$A2*B2 in Cell D2 and then drag it to E2 however I want to know how to do this using the column names.

[image]

Comment: perhaps it would be best to link an existing simple .xlsx file so that the reply/comments would be well focused

Comment: I'm not sure how to link but have put a picture. I think it is a simple thing. Essentially I want to be able to do something like the $ sign for when you reference a cell. I'm sure it will be possible but can't find how to.

Comment: please see an idea below

Answer (score 0):

perhaps e.g. the entire range (A3:A5) can be named "Multiplier"

then "Multiplier" can be used in the formula like below...

[image]

Comment: That does work but only will work if the multiplier is on the same row. Surely there is a way of referencing in absolute terms without this work around. Like if you want to reference one value in the column you use [@[]] there must be something for keeping it as is.

Comment: perhaps https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e?ocmsassetid=ha010155686&correlationid=630052ab-4b09-42ae-b643-4bc317c0b6f4&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us would help